# Setting up GUIs in R

Tags: r, user-interface

Trying to create some GUIs in R.
I create a window and it disappears.
What am I missing here?

```
library(tcltk)

tt <- tktoplevel()                  <br>
x <- tkbutton(tt, text = "Text")    <br>
tkpack(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What system do you use? It works just fine on macOS with R 3.4.1

[image]

This is strange. It should work fine from command line as well:

[image]

I assume that you have XQuartz (https://www.xquartz.org) installed and configured.

Comment: Thank you! I just tried it in R and it worked fine. I was trying to run it from the Mac terminal window, as a script "Rscript Filename.R" at the prompt. I'm not sure why it doesn't work there. I probably need to reference a certain package.

Comment: I made sure that I installed XQuartz. It still doesn't work from the terminal window, however. It appears and then disappears very quickly.